# Where is the Visual Basic COM project template?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, com, project-template

I was at a class recently, and the instructor started a new Visual Studio 2008 project using a "COM project" template. Now that I'm back, I tried finding that template in my installation of VS2008 with no luck. Does anybody know where I can find that template, or failing that, what it might be doing to achieve its effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it...it's not a project template, it's a class template.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look under the C++ templates?

**Edit**
VB.NET, I believe does not do COM projects.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned this was for VB.

Comment: Sure it does. You set the "Make assembly COM-Visible" under Assembly Information on the project's application tab, set "Register for COM interop" on the project's compile tab, create three guid constants for classid, interfaceid, and eventsid, and give them to the class's ComClass attribute. I'm just looking for an easier way.